# DOM element not updated after post jquery response

Tags: jquery, scroll, updating, jquery-tooltip

[Demo Page](http://www.arsdigital.com.br/biscoitex/page.php?page=produtos) DOM element not updated after post jquery response
I'm using this plug for jquery [link](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex5/stickytooltip.htm) combined with this script:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#produtos_div").scroll(function() {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() == $(this).get(0).scrollHeight) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "post",
          url: "more.php",
          success: function(data) {
              $("#produtos_div").append(data);
              $.post('addMenuShoppingCart.php', function(return){
                    $('#result').append(return);
                    stickytooltip.init("*[data-tooltip]", "mystickytooltip");
      })
          },
          error: function() {
          }
        });
 });
```

works when it is loaded but when u scroll and include the div elements from the post and try to reload the plug, there is an error: Object does not support this property or method. Since entering the new elements in a div with a new attr, but nothing works. If someone knows something please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve, simply create a method to add a copy of which is init but with one less line which was reviewed:

```
/ * stickytooltip.stickynotice1 stickytooltip.stickynotice1.join = ('') * /
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well the error happens because the `stickytooltip` object does not have a `destroy` method. I just did a quick search through `stickytooltip.js` and there is no destroy method in it either.

You didn't post the line where it happens, but it's in the code of the demo page you provided.

Comment: How can I implement destroy method?

Comment: Why do you want to? Remove that line. I don't understand why you put it there in the first place?

Comment: I try to implement destroy method destroying the variable that receives the method with the following syntax: delete stickytooltip but had no effect. I want to reload the function but I don´t know how.

Comment: Why? `init` will just reinitialise all tooktips.

Comment: My intention is to destroy and then recreate the DOM with the data that was inserted through the post, the code is missing the destroy method of the DOM to work. That is why I want you to help me build this method. How can I start?

Comment: How can I make the scroll tooltip to receive the new data?